# Stackoverflow Exception because of 'this.Content'?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, out-of-memory

So this sounds strange but I always get a stackoverflow exception when I execute 'this.Content' 3 times.

So I have a main window which stores all userControls so I dont have to create them always:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CreateSessionWindow csw;
    RateSessionWindow rsw;
    CloseSessionWindow closesw;
    MainMenuWindow mmw;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        csw = new CreateSessionWindow();
        rsw = new RateSessionWindow();
        closesw = new CloseSessionWindow();
        mmw = new MainMenuWindow();
        AllSessionWindows.csw = csw;
        AllSessionWindows.rsw = rsw;
        AllSessionWindows.closesw = closesw;
        AllSessionWindows.mmw = mmw;
    }

    private void bttnStartProgram_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Content = AllSessionWindows.mmw;
    }
}

public static class AllSessionWindows
{
    public static RateSessionWindow rsw;
    public static CloseSessionWindow closesw;
    public static CreateSessionWindow csw;
    public static MainMenuWindow mmw;

}
```

In my MainMenuWindow class I have a button and when I click on the button it changes the content:

```
public partial class MainMenuWindow : UserControl
{
    public MainMenuWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bttnCreateSession_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Content = AllSessionWindows.csw; //here
    }
}
```

And here is where I get usually the stackoverflowexception:

```
public partial class CreateSessionWindow : UserControl
{
    public CreateSessionWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bttnGoBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Content = AllSessionWindows.mmw; //here I always get the exception
    }
}
```

So no matter in which order I call this.Content (for eg. first mmw and than csw or csw and than mmw) I always get a stackoverflow Exception when I call it 3 times which you can see above. What could be the problem be?

Comment: Is there any other code that might be relevant here that we're missing? Like some code that does something to the content window?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt it is the only code I have. I mean I have other buttons but they don't do anything. I have not attached an eventlistener to them

Comment: Looks like you are maybe setting the Content of the Window to the Window itself. Makes sense that would cause an infinite loop (WPF UI objects form a visual tree, doing this would cause a cycle in this tree). Why are you setting the Content of Windows to other Window objects? It doesn't even make sense to me that WPF would even allow this.

Comment: @DaveM I have different UserControls for example for creating sessions, rating them etc. Instead of opening a new GUI for each Control I decided to use this.Content o I have only one loop.  What would be the answer to your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is `this.Content=...` in UserControls (in this case `this.Content` is `UserControl` content not `Window` content). If you want to change content in the main window you should add property with MainWindow to class `AllSessionWindows`:

```
public static class AllSessionWindows
{
    public static MainWindow MainWindow;
    public static RateSessionWindow rsw;
    public static CloseSessionWindow closesw;
    public static CreateSessionWindow csw;
    public static MainMenuWindow mmw;
}
```

In the MainWidnow constructor you must assign this property:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
 ...
     AllSessionWindows.MainWindow = this;
}
```

And in UserControl you should use following code:

```
private void bttnCreateSession_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AllSessionWindows.MainWindow.Content = AllSessionWindows.csw; 
}
```

Presented solution to this kind of problem by you is not the best solution. For this kind of problem, you can use [Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) framework.
In the following link you can find a good tutorial:

http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/1/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/

Your problem is described in part [5](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/3/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/) and [6](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2013/09/11/caliburn-micro-part-6-introduction-to-screens-and-conductors/) of this tutorial.